# Spark structured streaming kafka dependency cannot be resolved

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I tried

```
./spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1 test.py
```

in my own computer, everything is fine. But after i tried in my school's server, it has the following messages and errors. I have searched in Google for a long time and had no idea. Can anyone help me?

> Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/zqwang/.ivy2/cache The jars for the
>   packages stored in: /home/zqwang/.ivy2/jars :: loading settings :: url
>   = jar:file:/data/opt/tmp/zqwang/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
>   org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11 added as a dependency ::
>   resolving dependencies ::
>   org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-26b526c6-0535-4007-8428-e38188af5709;1.0
>     confs: [default] :: resolution report :: resolve 966ms :: artifacts
>   dl 0ms    :: modules in use:
>
> ---
>
> |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
>     |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
>
> ---
>
> |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
>
> ---
>
> :: problems summary :: :::: WARNINGS      module not found:
>   org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.3.1
>
> ==== local-m2-cache: tried
>
> file:/home/zqwang/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.3.1!spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11.jar:
>
> file:/home/zqwang/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.jar
>
> ==== local-ivy-cache: tried
>
> /home/zqwang/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/ivys/ivy.xml
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.3.1!spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11.jar:
>
> /home/zqwang/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11.jar
>
> ==== central: tried
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.3.1!spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11.jar:
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.jar
>
> ==== spark-packages: tried
>
> http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.pom
>
> ```
> -- artifact
> ```
>
> org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.3.1!spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11.jar:
>
> http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.jar
>
> ```
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
>
>   :: org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.3.1: not found
>
>   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> :::: ERRORS   Server access error at url
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.pom
>   (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
>
> Server access error at url
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.jar
>   (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
>
> Server access error at url
>   http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.pom
>   (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
>
> Server access error at url
>   http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.jar
>   (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
>
> :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency:
>   org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11;2.3.1: not found]  at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1303)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doPrepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:250)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:171)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But after i tried in my school's server, it has the following messages and errors

Your school has a firewall preventing remote packages from being downloaded.

This link works for me, for example

> Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11/2.3.1/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.1.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)

You'll need to download the Kafka jars outside of school, then use `--jars` flag to submit with them